# How to Run PHP Pages in CAKEPHP?

Tags: php, cakephp

i configured database in xampp. but i don't know no how to run php pages in cake php .

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/4/Beginning-With-CakePHP).That would be good assistant.